# Accessing static Spring Boot files from Apache

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an Apache Web Server with this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@elcor.com
  ServerName  elcor.com
  ServerAlias www.elcor.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/home.html
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/html

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/elcor.com/public_html
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/elcor.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/elcor.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I access the Spring Boot app directly with `http://localhost:8080/home.html`, everythng is fine,
but when I do it through the Apache Web Server (`http://elcor.com`) all the public matchers (`*.css`, `*.js..`) I 've defined in the Spring Boot security file are not public anymore and it redirects fo login for those files.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(publicMatchers()).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/joan.html")
            .failureUrl("/login.html?error").permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout().permitAll();
}
```

Comment: Could you add Spring Security's logs? You have to set logger to `DEBUG` for Spring Security to see its logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your Spring application is also serving your static resources, js and CSS, you need to configure Apache in a way that allows you to route traffic to your application in order to find those resources.

Please, try this change in your Apache configuration:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080
```

As you can see, the idea is to route all traffic received in the root path of your webserver to your Spring application.

I think this change can be of help in order to resolve your issue.

In addition, you can instruct Spring Security to ignore this kind of resources. You can implement this functionality in your Spring Security configuration class by overriding this method:

```java
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web
    .ignoring()
       // You can also ignore other resources like images, fonts, etcetera
      .antMatchers("/**/*.js")
      .antMatchers("/**/*.css");
}
```